# ngFor items getting appended instead of simple updating

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular2-template, ngfor

In my Angular 4 app, when I update an array with new values, instead of showing me the new values the values are getting appended to the DOM. I have used ngFor a million times before, but never faced such weird behaviour.

Here is my html

```
<div class="roles-list" *ngIf="branchEmployees && branchEmployees.length > 0">
          <div class="roles-item" *ngFor="let branchEmployee of branchEmployees">
            <div class="branch-image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + branchEmployee.branch.organisation.profile_photo_urls.thumb + ')'}">
            </div>
            <div class="branch-name">
              {{ branchEmployee.branch.name }}
            </div>
            <div class="branch-employee-role">
              <select (change)="employeeRoleChange($event.target.value, branchEmployee.id)" [(ngModel)]="branchEmployee.access_type">
                <option value="user">{{'User'}}</option>
                <option value="admin">{{'Admin'}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my component

```
this.branchEmployees = [];
this.model.get({name: `people/${this.selectedEmployee.person.id}/branch_employees`}).subscribe(branchEmployees => {
  this.branchEmployees = branchEmployees
})
```

The above code in component runs on the click of some button.
I can verify that the variable this.branchEmployees has the proper number of values, but somehow these values are not being replaced in the DOM but getting appended, also this behaviour is not just for this ngFor, it's for every ngFor loop in the this component!

Comment: What does a `branchEmployee` look like? Do they have an unique id?

Comment: Yea, they have uni ids, but it doesn't matter because what it containes, because at the end of the day, it's an item of an array

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted your question. `*ngFor` doesn't do this. If you don't want elements to be rendered, you need to remove them from `branchEmployees`. If you always add, `*ngFor` will always add.

Comment: See the code in the component, I'm emptying the array just to be sure, and then putting inside new values.
Now suppose my array contains previously 2 values, 
Now I empty them, 
Add new values(lets say 4)
Now this.branchEmployees has 4 values
But in the dom, there are 6 values, 2 previous and 4 new

Comment: I assume `model.get()` keeps old values and `this.branchEmployees = branchEmployees` is an ever growing array. I can ensure you `*ngFor` itself doesn't do that.

Comment: yea, that's what even I was astonished for, debugged that thing for 3-4 times, but to my surprise, that variable stores pure fresh values

Comment: And model.get is nothing but an api call, and it doesn't store previous values

Comment: Try to make a reproduction in http://stackblitz.com. I doubt your question contains enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this, but the http method is not working I guess in angular 5 of stackblitz, can you check that?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1dyyh
Also open the app link in new window and allow unsafe script as the api is in http not https

Comment: You could also try to add `console.log(branchEmployees);` to the `subscribe(...)` callback to see what the data looks like.

Comment: it's not getting into a success callback but rather an error callback with status as 0 and error text as "unknown error"

Comment: I meant in your local project. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kasunq works for me though. I wrapped data in `[...]` because the HTTP request doesn't return an array.

Comment: I'm working on providing a proper reproduciton, that's not the proper case though

Comment: Have you tried `console.log` in `subscribe(...)`?

Comment: No bro, I don't get the success callback as I said earlier.
Can we pair programme?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time. I also don't understand what you mean with success callback. How can your list grow if you don't get a success callback?

Comment: I'm not getting success callbacks in the stackblitz app

Comment: Try it in your local project

Answer (score 0):

The better way of writing the code in your question is to move

```
this.branchEmployees = [];
```

inside the callback function of the asynchronous call, like this:

```
    this.model.get({name: `people/${this.selectedEmployee.person.id}/branch_employees`}).subscribe(branchEmployees => {
      this.branchEmployees = [];
      this.branchEmployees = branchEmployees
    })
```

On one side, it will flush the data in the list when new data is fetched and
that you are able to keep/paint the data of your list `branchEmployees`, even if the call fails/delayed over the network (service or server or some other resource is not available or broken).